# Library for drawing images in the browser

Tags: image, javascript

Is there a javascript library to draw images directly in the browser and save them to png or jpeg?

I want to use an alternative to services like aviary.com, pixlr.com and sumopaint.com and dont want to rely on third-party services and apis like these ones.

Is processingjs the right solution? I want a solution that works everywhere so please no nodejs and so on.

I need tools like a brush, paintbrush, pencil, layers, filters and so on - just like the real photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also draw all sorts of images and animations using http://paperjs.org/

Then you can save them using straightforward JS:

```
var canvas           = document.getElementById("my_canvas_element");
var imageToExport    = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: so whats better? paperjs or processingjs?

Answer (score 0):

Try [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/)

For image saving, just use data-urls:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
[Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)